# Question about non-specific templates when using nested templates

Tags: c++, templates

Why `test<std::vector<int> >();` is wrong?

How to comprehend the usage of `typename` in `template <template <typename T, typename AllocT > typename ContainerT>`?

Here is the code snippet:

```
template <template <typename T, typename AllocT > typename ContainerT>
test()
{
    ContainerT<int, my::Allocator<int> > container.
}

int main()
{
     test<std::vector>();
     test<std::list>();
     test<std::set>();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters at template template parameter there are few examples.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the `typename` keyword simply means that the template parameter is a type parameter.

Comment: You mean `ContainerT` is equivalent to `template <template <typename T, typename AllocT > typename ContainerT>`?